# Change FontSize to fit TextBlock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I'm developing Windows 8 Store Application, we know that display sizes are very different, so all the elements have stretchable settings, so that if display is small elements (pictures, charts etc. ) are smaller, if display is big - bigger.

All works perfectly except TextBlocks (labels):

TextBlock element itself also is being stretched, but the FontSize remains the same, how i noticed there is no property to change font size to fit TextBlock.

Is there a way to change FontSize of the TextBlock to fit the container? Examples are wery appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grow/shrink a TextBlock (Font Size) to the available space in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794355/how-to-grow-shrink-a-textblock-font-size-to-the-available-space-in-wpf)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try putting the text inside the control into a `Viewbox`:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Width="50" Height="50">
    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
</Viewbox>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4794427/1230188)